# MapKit functionality on a UIImage, dropping pins/Annotation

Tags: swift, uiimageview, mapkit, mapkitannotation

I am trying to use the existing MapKit functionality on an image.
What I am trying to achieve is to drop pins on an image and maybe add notes on these pins.
I have managed to give the user the possibility to add a pin dynamically with a longGesture but I don't know how to achieve the same on an image.

My code is as follows:

```swift
import UIKit
import MapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController , MKMapViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
    var keyLat:String = "49.2768"
    var keyLon:String = "-123.1120"
    @IBOutlet weak var image: UIImageView!
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        mapView.delegate = self
        
        let longPressRecogniser = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleTap(_:)))
        longPressRecogniser.minimumPressDuration = 0.5
        mapView.addGestureRecognizer(longPressRecogniser)
        
        mapView.mapType = MKMapType.standard
        
        let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: CLLocationDegrees(keyLat.toFloat()),longitude: CLLocationDegrees(keyLon.toFloat()))
        
        let span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.05, longitudeDelta: 0.05)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location, span: span)
        mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
        
        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        annotation.coordinate = location
        annotation.title = "MY Pin"
        annotation.subtitle = "On the Map"
        mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
    }

    
    @objc func handleTap(_ gestureReconizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer)
    {
        
        let location = gestureReconizer.location(in: mapView)
        let coordinate = mapView.convert(location,toCoordinateFrom: mapView)
        
        // Add annotation:
        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        annotation.coordinate = coordinate
        annotation.title = "latitude:" + String(format: "%.02f",annotation.coordinate.latitude) + "& longitude:" + String(format: "%.02f",annotation.coordinate.longitude)
        mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
        
    }
    
    
    var selectedAnnotation: MKPointAnnotation?
    
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
        
        let latValStr : String = String(format: "%.02f",Float((view.annotation?.coordinate.latitude)!))
        let lonvalStr : String = String(format: "%.02f",Float((view.annotation?.coordinate.longitude)!))
        
        print("latitude: \(latValStr) & longitude: \(lonvalStr)")
    }
    
}
```

any help will be really appreciated.
Thanks
George

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same can be achieved by following the same procedure with a few tweaks here and there. I've made a sample `ViewController` that demonstrates how you can add pointers (`UIViews` in this case) into a `UIImageView`.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView! // Image view

    lazy var longPress = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didLongPressScreen)) // long press gesture

    // MARK: LifeCycle
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        setup()
    }

    // MARK: Functions
    private func setup() {
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "photo")

        imageView.addGestureRecognizer(longPress) // Adding gesture recognizer 
        imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true // ImageViews are not user interactive by default

    }

    // UILongPressGestureRecognizer Action
    @objc func didLongPressScreen(_ sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
        let location = sender.location(in: self.view) //Getting location

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let pointer = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20))
            pointer.backgroundColor = .red
            pointer.center = location // Setting the center of the view to the x,y coordinates of the long press
            self.view.addSubview(pointer) // Adding the UIView to the view
        }
    }
}
```

The most important part of this is to enable the user interaction for the `UIImageView` as its. `isUserInteractionEnabled` is set to `false` by default. The output of the above can be seen below,

[image]

Comment: @ Visal Rajapakse - Thank you very much, for such an accurate answer! May I ask you if there is the possibility to add a note on the drop pin and if there is the possibility to add this functionality on a WKWebView that I use to present pictures in a pdf format?

Comment: Happy to help :). What do you mean by the "drop pin" is it the pin in the image? Adding to this, I'm not familiar with WebViews, but one thing is that for pdfs you can use Apples **PDFKit** that gives you a host of functionality.

Comment: @ Visal Rajapakse -Thanks Visal! Yes I was wondering if I can add a text in a form of Title-Subtitle for the red squares so when I choose it to pop up. I am reading about the PDFKit as we speak but I can't find any sample code to experiment..

Comment: Well, anything is possible :). I would also suggest that you look into `UIPopover`'s, they can make what you are about to do pretty easy I believe. For the latter, I would recommend [Raywenderlichs PDFKit](https://www.raywenderlich.com/4023941-creating-a-pdf-in-swift-with-pdfkit) tutorial. But to suit your needs you will have to do some additional googling